# Confluence Macro Plugin properties

Tags: java, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I created a plugin (Java) that have the following snippet:

```
        String username = "abcdef";
        String passowrd = "somepass";
        String userName = URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        String password = URLEncoder.encode(passowrd, "UTF-8");

        String url = String.format("https://example.com?format=username=%s&password=%s", userName, password);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I would like to allow the user to change the username and pasword from within Confluence, so I have been struggling to use and know whether there is a way to store the username and password in Confluence (properties if there is such a thing), and then read them into the Java application in the plugin, the latter is not important.

Comment: Depends on your configurations. Normally user names are located in 'cwd_users' table and passwords are encrypted tho. It's not a good practice to change the usernames since you may mess up with the contents what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if you want your plugin to store some data then you should take a look at Active Objects. It is the plugin data storage component in Atlasssian.